# Restating the question in an answer

Tags: discussion

For the question [SendInput %userInput% causes my computer to malfunction oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086256/my-script-crashes-my-computer), I provided a solution that got voted down. I don't know why it was voted down because the answer in itself was invalid, or because I restated my question in there, or a combination of both.

It makes sense that you should not ask questions in an answer, because they are two contradictory states that should not conjunct. But I don't feel I violated that etiquette at all, for I restated the actual question by means of which I wanted to emphasize that the core of the problem wasn't addressed with my answer. It is a workaround and a working alternative, but it didn't explain the reason as to why SendInput was crashing my computer.

Why is such a restatement classified as bad etiquette?

UPDATE:
Several answers were given which prompted me to motivate myself better. To restate this in a comment format is impractical, so I do it as an update. Please inform me if there is a better way of doing this.

First of all, I agree that the answer and the workaround provided is not the best one. However, it IS a workable answer that provided me a way of dealing with this problem until a better solution came about. It answered my specific need. As such, I don't feel that it makes sense you down vote the answer simply because it is not the most optimal one.

As far as restating the question is concerned:
First of all, there are many ways of answering a question. One of the ways is to ask good questions. Core questions that help identify the problem are definitely valid questions. The question I stated in the answer really addressed the essence of the whole matter in two ways:

One that my answer is weak because it is not addressing the main issue. It is merely avoiding it.

Two, a restating of the core issue in this whole question. As such, it is not a question like: What is your age? It is a rhetorical question. Both types of questions look grammatically the same. They both have a question mark. But the purpose is different. Questions are to be evaluated, whereas rhetorical questions are there to guide or emphasize. Think about the teaching style of Socrates. His questions were posed not to evaluate you, but to help you get to the correct answer.

I feel that people are merely picking on this issue because of mere syntax. Just because it looks like a question, it got down voted. But it is a question that rather summarized and encapsulated the whole issue in the two dimensions I stated above. I could have done it differently:

> Answer: Avoid SendInput and use clipboard instead. However, there must
>   be a way of doing this with SendInput as well. It is a matter of
>   understanding what is there inside %userInput% that causes the script
>   to crash when a SendInput is performed.

Nobody would have debated with me that the above is a good format of an answer. So how does that change when I change it into a rhetorical question?

As such, rhetorical questions should not be a cause of noise in the answering format. Also note it would be utterly ridiculous for me to post a whole new question dedicated to posing a rhetorical question when it is currently being addressed.

Comment: The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of useful programming knowledge to help the programming community.  In other words, *posts should be useful to others.*  The best way that can be achieved is by each post being as clean and free of noise as possible.  Overall, does it seem like your post achieves this goal?

Comment: I edited the question, to motivate why my format was not a cause for additional noise to the question. In summary, it is a rhetorical question. Questions that are blameworthy is when they can have an independent existence in a new thread. My question was restating the essence of the whole problem.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with AutoHotkey, but at first read your answer doesn't read like an answer.  It honestly reads as a very "forum-like" follow up answer & question, so I can see why it was downvoted, and based on a quick read, I can envision a moderator deleting the post if someone flagged it as "Not An Answer".

You pretty much hit on the reason in your question here.  Answers should be Answers, Questions should be Questions.  Forum-like conversation is strongly discouraged.  Generally when someone edits their solution into the question, we try to edit it out and put that solution in a separate answer.  Likewise, reasking the question in an answer is almost the same problem.  There is a difference between quoting the question and reasking the question.  There are times where you want to quote the original question into order address specific points, but unless you are quoting then you are effectively reasking the question.

The reasoning is we like things with a little noise as possible, and we don't like conversation in posts.  Your first 2 sentences are an answer<sup>1</sup>.  The rest of the answer is just extra info that does not add anything to the answer.

<sup>1 - Despite it being an answer, it is a weak answer.  You should add some more content - like some more details on your script that you used in order to make it into a real answer</sup>

Comment: That impression can get created because of the syntax. But we are more advanced than computers to understand and differentiate between the usage and application of syntax according to the situation. The question I posed was a rhetorical question to put attention to the weakness of my answer in the sense it is not addressing the core issue. In order to achieve that, I phrased the core issue in a question format, that in the context is to be understood as a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 5):

The comment makes it pretty clear that he doesn't feel you're restating the question, you're asking a different one and that isn't why the answer was downvoted; he has several other problems with its content.

As to whether or not those other concerns are valid, I couldn't say, but they do seem to be the primary reason for his downvote (assuming the person who commented even did downvote; we can't know that).

Comment: That could be possible that he feels I am asking a completely different question. However, in that case he didn't understand the original question I put forward. I edited the question to make my standpoint come out clearer. I feel that people are regarding it as a violation merely because of it having the syntax of a question, eg a question mark rather than looking at the type of question I posed. It is not a question like: "What is your age?" It is rather a question posed to summarize the whole issue in one sentence and to prompt people to focus on that instead of my temporary workaround.

Comment: @Khalil That would be something to discuss with that user, not with me.

Comment: Such a question is a rhetorical question and ought to have its place in the answering section. Please read the edit update for more clarification.

Comment: :) That is correct. I already discussed it with him, and you also understood the same thing as I did, namely that he regards it as a different question altogether. I am not writing this to debate with you specifically, but for those who are reading your answer and voting you up, to have a correct perspective on it. I think nobody feels I am asking a completely different question here?

Comment: To put it differently, your answer seems to be putting the blame entirely on me. That I am asking a completely unrelated question. I am merely commenting on your post to put things in perspective, because other people seem to be agreeing with you, even though you are not debating that point. You are merely stating an observation.

Comment: I'm telling you that the other person is commenting on the content of your post *in addition to the form* and that you shouldn't get *too* caught up in thinking that he's being pedantic in addressing your form.  From his comments, it appears he has issues with your *content*.  I specifically stated that I don't know if he is correct, or if you were.  I don't see how this answer is in any way ambiguous on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

When you restate something, it helps to put it in block quotes. For example here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100073/1822514) in block quotes:

> A good workaround that I found was to avoid SendInput altogether. Rather use the clipboard to copy the string inside, to then paste it on your screen. It works flawlessly, and is a billion times faster. Why would a person utilize SendInput in the first place? However, the actual question still is standing, why does SendInput behave so strangely? What is inside that string: %userInput% that causes my system to crash? How can I find out?

When you look at the above, it is clear that I am quoting your answer.

Now onto what I think can be done to improve how you presented the above.  If you look at your text, it is very difficult to tell what content is yours, and what content is the OPs (what is being restated).

Perhaps you could have done something like this:

---

> Why does SendInput behave so strangely? What is inside that string: %userInput% that causes my system to crash? How can I find out?

Why would a person utilize SendInput in the first place?

A good workaround that I found was to avoid SendInput altogether. Rather use the clipboard to copy the string inside, to then paste it on your screen. It works flawlessly, and is a billion times faster.

---

If you look at the above, the OP's question is in block quotes and clearly stands out. Also, your answer follows the question - this makes it look like you are answering the question, rather than asking a new question.

Comment: I really like your idea of putting it forward like that. However, I feel the essence of my statement will get lost if I did it like that. You see, If I did it like you suggested, then it would have been a real question. I was not intending to do that. I was merely intending to pose a rhetorical question to guide the attention of people to the core aspect of the problem. I was saying: This is a good workaround that helped me, however, don't think the ultimate answer has been arrived at as yet. The core issue is still standing, which is...

Comment: Also, putting my answer under that would have been inappropriate for the reason that the quoted question is not getting answered at all. So why would I raise it in the first place?

Comment: @Khalil - Instead of this text: "Why would a person utilize SendInput in the first place?", I would just state that SendInput has these problems: (list the problems). Then you can suggest that the user use your solution instead. I don't see any problem with quoting the user and doing that.

Answer (score 1):

[You answered your own question... Or did you?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)

> A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question
>   that is asked in order to make a point.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) The question is used as a
>   rhetorical device, posed for the sake of encouraging its listener to
>   consider a message or viewpoint. Though these are technically
>   questions, they do not always require a question mark. A rhetorical
>   question does not usually require an immediate answer, but **is meant to
>   draw attention to and start a meaningful discussion on the matter.**

Hence rhetorical questions should be used cautiously on Stackoverflow, as discussions are discouraged and are generally considered "noise".

In this particular case using rhetorical questions to point out that your "answer is weak because it is not addressing the main issue. It is merely avoiding it."  and then eluding to the possibility that there is perhaps a much better answer that you were either unwilling or unable to provide and leaving that open to discussion, makes for a weak answer indeed. Other users pointed out the flawed approach and you gathered downvotes.

Had you answered with:

> Avoid SendInput and use clipboard instead. However, there must be a
>   way of doing this with SendInput as well. It is a matter of
>   understanding what is there inside %userInput% that causes the script
>   to crash when a SendInput is performed.

It may have been a bit better, but you still didn't include why the solutions that you mention are workable, they are statements without any supporting facts, references, or explanation and thus still make for a weak answer and would likely still gather a downvote or two.